# Resolve template in AngularJS similar to Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, handlebars.js

How to resolve an AngularJS template with a syntax similar to Handlebar?

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="mytemplate">
  Name is {{name}}
</script>
```

I can get the template using $templateCache.get('mytemplate') buthow to resolve that template to a valid HTML that can be inserted into DOM.

For example:

```
var html = $templateCache.get('mytemplate', {name: 'Ace' });
```

should output "Name is Ace"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this, but I think it will work.

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
scope.name = 'Ace';
var html = $compile($templateCache.get('myTemplate'))(scope);
```

Basically, create a Scope, set values on it and then pass it into a compiled template.

Comment: Thanks, it works. It returns a DOM element instead of HTML, but works for me.

Comment: If you need the HTML itself call html.html();