# Visjs timeline with angularjs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vis.js, ng-template, angularjs-ng-template

I want to use the [Timeline](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline) from visjs.org in my AngularJS application. To render the individual cells I want to use an AngularJS template.

On the visjs.org site I can find an [example](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Templates) of a Handlebars template, which is working fine.

However I want to use some AngularJS functionality (like i18n filters etc) so I prefer to have a "text/ng-template" template but I don't know how to configure visjs to use AngularJS templates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pls share what you have done to throw light on your requirement

Comment: I've followed the example with HandleBars. I don't know how to link to the AngularJS template.

Comment: can you pls share the html and javascript code you had done for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My primary suggestion to use create a directive or component in new angular version for visjs.
or use [angular-visjs](https://github.com/visjs/angular-visjs), a directive module developed by visjs team inoder to support angular projects. But you need to consider the following note from the developers

> NOTE: This library is currently being refactored. The intention is make the directives simpler, removing the additional 'non-vis.js' related directives (such as time-board and time-navigation), and bring the DataSet factory in-line with the vis.DataSet such that the documentation for vis is fully (hopefully) applicable and consistent.
>
> ```
>                      -The note was taken from ReadMe File on 4 th March 2017
> ```

For using template like handlebars you can refer another post from stack overflow itself

[Resolve template in AngularJS similar to Handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203125/resolve-template-in-angularjs-similar-to-handlebars)